# How to always allow access to phone data automatically for USB connection of Android 8?

Tags: android, mobile

I have a testing mobile device Galaxy J5 Prime with Android version 8.0.0 and Samsung Experience version 9.0

I often have to plug in and plug out this device through USB connection and every time I plug smartphone in the next message on smartphone screen pops-up:

"Allow access to phone data?

The connecter device will be able to access data on this phone.

DENY/ALLOW"

Clicking "Allow" every time takes time.
Is there any way to set the "Allow" option by default so I won't have to confirm every time?

Comment: I would suggest you to re-post this question on StackOverflow - it seems more directed to it and you will have a boarder audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the driver for Samsung Mobile USB Composite Device to the latest version should resolve this issue.

For Windows 10:

1. Start
2. Device manager
3. Navigate to USB Controllers
4. Find Samsung Mobile USB Composite Device
5. Click Update driver
6. Restart PC
7. Reconnect mobile phone via USB cable
8. Confirm prompt with "Allow"

Now you should not see this prompt anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to do the same on MAC?

Comment: https://developer.samsung.com/android-usb-driver

I ended up installing the driver from above and it seems to be remove the repetitive prompt